# Valid MRL address in VLC plugin in C++ using WinForms?

Tags: c++, winforms, user-interface, vlc

In a GUI I'm working on I intend to use VLC (axVLCplguin) to display camera feed. I want to test it with an offline video stored on my disc, however, each time I click on the button, which should start the video, I get a runtime error (caused on line  **VLC** -> **playlist** -> **add(path, NULL, NULL);** ).

I assume, that the given MRL address - the first parameter of the method - is not in a correct format: `file://C:/Users/User/Desktop/AMT.mp4`
(viz.: https://wiki.videolan.org/Media_resource_locator/).

I've seen many tutorials, how to get a video feed in WinForms using the VLC plugin, but none of them had an included code in C++ (only in C#, where the simple absolute path to the video did the work).

```
void Grimr::MainForm::chbox_live_CheckedChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    pbox_drawing->Visible = false;
    if (chbox_area->Checked)
    {
        VLC->Visible = true;
        VLC->AutoPlay = false;
        String^ path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\AMT.mp4";
        VLC->playlist->add(path, NULL, NULL);
        VLC->playlist->play();
    }
}
```

Comment: axVLCplguin is NOT supported anymore, for a long time. Please use libvlcpp (C++) or libvlcsharp (dotnet)

Comment: Is there any tutorial on 'how to import libvlcpp to visual studio project'? The github readme only contains links to the documentation of library(functions etc.).